# $\Phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ , $f$ is R.I. $\rightarrow \Phi \circ f$ is R.I.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, riemann-integration

> $\Phi : \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous and $\Phi(0)=0$. Suppose that $f$ is Riemann Integrable. Show that $\Phi \circ f$ is also R.I.

I assumed $f$ has bounded support $[a,b]$. Thus $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [m,M]$

Since $\Phi$ is continuous on the whole real line, it's also continuous on $[m,M]$, meaning it's also R.I.

Is this correct? Why do we need the $\Phi(0)=0$ condition?

Comment: You don't need the extra condition, but I don't understand your proof. How does the fact that $\Phi|_{[m,M]}$ is Riemann integrable helps you to deduce that $\Phi \circ f$ is Riemann integrable?

Comment: Better use one characterization of RI and that $\Phi$ is uniformly continuous of $[m, M]$.

Comment: $\Phi \circ f$ is the same as $\Phi (f(x))$ for $x\in [a,b]$, then $\Phi(y)$ where $y\in [m,M]$ gets mapped to something bounded, using definition of continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to expand a little on Adelafif's correct but IMO overly concise answer.  For starters we have Baby Rudin 11.33:  "Suppose $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$. Then $f\in{\mathcal R}$ [the Riemann-integrable functions] on $[a,b]$ if and only if $f$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[a,b]$."  Here "almost everywhere" means "except on a set of Lebesgue measure zero."

OK, suppose now that $A$ is that set of Lebesgue measure zero where $f$ is not continuous.  For $x\in[a,b]\setminus A$, we have $f$ continuous at $x$, and by hypothesis $\Phi$ is continuous at $f(x)$ (Baby Rudin 4.7), so $\Phi \circ f$ is continuous at $x$ too.  Thus $\Phi \circ f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ except on the same set of measure zero, namely $A$, and is thus Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 2):

continuous of continuous is continuous. A function is R-integrable iff it is bounded and a.e cont. The result follows.

Comment: does $f$ being R.I. imply that $f$ is continuous? A step function is R.I. , but not continuous

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This is the (at least "a") correct answer. Note that the answer just says that an R.I. function is a.e. (**almost everywhere**) continuous, not necessarily everywhere.

Comment: @PhoemueX: I think the wording is not very clear and therefore some downvotes were given. I have added my +1 to compensate because this is a correct answer.